# Android: do i need to setup Drawer "burger icon" onClickListener?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Im trying to setup an activity with a drawer and a toolbar/action bar, but im having some problems with the setup.

My **main_activity.xml**:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp”>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_tool_bar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<!--... the rest of my layout for the drawer...-->
```

My toolbar.xml:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_color"/>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private void setupToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_white);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.to_sign));

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });

        setActionBarTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}


    //........ more code not related with bar or drawer.........

}
```

I would like to be able to change background color, text color and icon (navigation burger, or any other icon) without using XML configuration (theme).

As i understood, setSupportActionBar(toolbar) would do implement the clickListener for me. But when i don't specify the listener, the button simply doesnt work (no action at all).

Comment: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: @Simas, i just update my question. You are right, one questions at the time its more clear for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd listen to the drawer's open/close events with a drawer listener. When creating this listener you can specify the toolbar and then your button will work.

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    ...
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, getToolbar(),
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Of course you may choose not to override the methods and just use a plain `ActionBarDrawerToggle` object.

This is (mostly) code that's generated by default in AndroidStudio when you create an activity with a drawer so I consider it as best practice.